# "requests.get"/beautifulSoup returns different result each call on the same URL

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

There's a website when users can add products, and I want to scrape the product a given user (me) has added to the webpage.

I have the following so far:

```py
from fake_headers import Headers
import requests

def get_page(link):
    #Get the product-links
    headers = Headers(headers=True)
    n_tries = 0
    max_n_tries = 5
    is_valid = False

    while (not is_valid) & (n_tries<max_n_tries):
        try:
            head = headers.generate()
            r = requests.get(link,headers=head,timeout=10)
            is_valid =  r.status_code==200  #Try 5 different headers. If no timeout and no 200 -> invalid url
            n_tries +=1
        except TimeoutError:
            n_tries +=1

    if n_tries==max_n_tries:
        return 404

    page = r.text
    return page


link = "https://xn--nskeskyen-k8a.dk/share/Jakob_Daller"
page = get_page(link)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")
#Get saved items
results = soup.find_all('a')
products = [x['href'] for x in results if x.text.strip() == 'LINK']
```

and with the same `link`, `products` sometimes returns two items, sometimes one. When returning two, it ain't always the same items aswell (there's three items on `link` atm). After a bit, it returns all three items all the time. This happens each time I delete/add an item on the page.

Note, if I inspect the page in my browser, I can see all the items all the time.

The same happens if I just use `page = requests.get(link).text` with no headers.¨

Since I cannot inspect the entire `page`-body I don't know if it's due to BeautifulSoup or to the body returned by `requests`.

Comment: And what's that website?

Comment: I did not include that since I didnt' thought it would matter. But have updated the questin

Comment: There just seems to be an inconsistancy between what the browser (Firefox) shows and what the `request` gets.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `bs4` for this. There's an API you can get the data from.

Try this:

```py
import requests

response = requests.get("https://api.xn--nskeskyen-k8a.dk/api/share/Jakob_Daller")

for wish in response.json()["wishes"]:
    print(f"{wish['title']}\n{wish['trackingUrl']}")
```

Output:

```
Molo CANDI - Jerseykjoler - red/rød - Zalando.dk
https://xn--nskeskyen-k8a.dk/api/redirect/wish/38317697
Molo FLORIE - Overall / Jumpsuit /Buksedragter - multi-coloured/flerfarvet - Zalando.dk
https://xn--nskeskyen-k8a.dk/api/redirect/wish/38317401
```

Comment: Thanks! It does solve the problem for the given link/webpage but it does not *answer* the question to why it happens. I.e when I can see the links in the browser, how come I cannot scrape it? In case the `api` is removed I still would like to be able to scrape from the "raw" page

Comment: You cannot scrape them because of JavaScript. Turn it off and you'll see what `bs4` sees as the HTML you request for. In other words, the tags you think you get are simply not there in the source.

Comment: The wierd thing is that it works (most of the time). After some minutes I can scrape them as above, the issue is when the list is changed. When disabling javaScript I cannot see anything, but requests find most of the content

Comment: What you see in the browser *is not* what you get when you request for the HTML. The content is generated dynamically by JavaScript. There's *nothing* weird about it. `requests` sees it because it gets a JSON object, which, by the way is your content for the webpage.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a bunch. Feel free to add the JavaScript part to your answer and I'll gladly accept it

Comment: I think my answer is complete as is. In order to get the JavaScript part scraped you'd need to explore [selenium with Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).